# Line thickness ggplot - looks discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, thickness

I would like to plot two lines with different thicknesses. `size` argument works, but only partially.

```
library(ggplot2)

forecast <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3)
actual <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,1)

my_df <- data.frame(forecast = forecast, actual = actual)
my_df$seq_order <- as.factor(1:NROW(my_df))
my_df <-gather(my_df, "line_type", "value", -seq_order)

my_df$line_size <- 1
my_df[my_df$line_type =="actual", "line_size"] <- 5

ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=seq_order, y = value,
        colour = line_type, group=line_type, size= line_size))+geom_line()+
  scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("forecast" = "blue" ,"actual" = "green"))
```

Here is what it generates:

[image: plot]

However, changing `my_df[my_df$line_type =="actual", "line_size"] <- 2` does not visibly affect anything.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result here? I'm not sure I understand what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `scale_size_identity`.

```
ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=seq_order, y = value,
        colour = line_type, group=line_type, size= line_size))+geom_line()+ 
  scale_size_identity(guide=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("forecast" = "blue" ,"actual" = "green"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but generates message: `Scale for 'size' is already present. Adding another scale for
'size', which will replace the existing scale.`

Comment: @user1700890 you probably have two different `scale_size_...` calls in your plot

Comment: @Tjebo, thank you, Yes, I have two `scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE)` to get rid off legend (it is in my original post) and `scale_size_identity(guide=FALSE)` to control thickness (from the answer). I need them both. What should I do?

Comment: @user1700890 remove the continuous one and see what happens

Comment: @Tjebo, you are correct. I removed `scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE)` and nothing changed. I have both thickness control and no legend